# insert separator between view-pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

How could i insert some padding between the pages inside view-pager  like in the market app - the black line  [image]

Comment: add view with black color. height as match and width as 3dp.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That is a new api for the `ViewPager` called the margin, a link to it can be found [`setPageMargin()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setPageMargin%28int%29). Make sure you are using the latest support library.

Answer (score 34):

This worked for me.  I just set the margin and filled it with a color.

```
viewPager.setPageMargin(20); // TODO Convert 'px' to 'dp'
viewPager.setPageMarginDrawable(R.color.black);
```

EDIT: To convert dp to pixel conversion I used:

```
int px = Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
mViewPager.setPageMargin(px);
mViewPager.setPageMarginDrawable(R.color.black);
```

Comment: Note that `setPageMargin(int)` takes a pixel value. Instead of providing a number, you might want to do dp conversions.

Answer (score 2):

Use This method:

```
public void setPageMarginDrawable (int resId)
```

You will be able to set a drawable that will be used to fill the **margin** between pages.