# Android implemeneting Gmail viewpager outline border

Tags: android

this below screen shot is Gmail `viewpager` which that implemented outline borders for viewpager `Fragments`

**swipe from left to right**

[image]

**swipe from right to left**

[image]

**And** now i want to implementing that for my application but can design that:

**swipe from left to right**

[image]

**swipe from right to left**

[image]

My root layout xml is:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="-30dp"
    android:background="#949494"
    android:paddingLeft="-15dp"
    android:paddingRight="-15dp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:background="#ffffff">

        ...

    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want something like this? 
[insert separator between view-pager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935127/insert-separator-between-view-pager)

You can use a margin drawable to reproduce the style.

Comment: i think this viewpager has 3 layout, with 3 color, which you can see on my topic

Comment: A drawable does not have to be a solid color. A drawable can also be a an object with multiple colors or a 9 patch

Answer (score 0):

My solution to implementing viewpager like with Gmail

Result:

[image]

**viewPager root layout:**

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#d1d1d1">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vp_horizontal_ntb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>
```

**fragment layout:**

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="-20dp"
    android:background="#eeeeee">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:background="#ffffff">
    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

and setPageMargin:

```
viewPager.setPageMargin(80);
```